# Pandoc Checklist/Checkbox/Tasklist generation using task_lists Extension doesn't work

Tags: markdown, pandoc, epub, file-conversion, epub3

I checked `pandoc --list-extensions=markdown` and `pandoc --list-extensions=gfm` whether `+task_lists` is supported, and it is. However, even with that, I can't render checklists using `tasks_lists` while generating an `EPUB` file from `markdown` or `gfm`.

Is there anything I'm missing in this command?
`pandoc --from gfm+task_lists --to epub3 README.md --output ABC.epub --epub-cover-image=images/promotional.png --metadata title="My Title" --metadata author="Daniel Danielecki" --toc --number-sections --shift-heading-level-by=-2`

My `Markdown` example:

```
### Some text

- [x] Yes.
- [ ] No.
```

Pandoc version:

```
pandoc --version
pandoc 3.1.6.1
Features: +server +lua
Scripting engine: Lua 5.4
User data directory: /Users/danieldanielecki/.local/share/pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2023 John MacFarlane. Web: https://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is no
warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.
```

as per https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3051 it should work already for quite some time

PS. Converting to `HTML` works 100% fine, but not to `EPUB`.